# onBlur function - setState incorrect

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, onblur

I am trying to run an unit test for the following code. I already test onClick and onChange and this.props

onBlur seems not to be working correctly based on the setState

Here is the method that onBlur is calling

```
 handleChange = (e) => {
let localState = Object.assign({}, this.state)
localState[e.target.name] = e.target.value
let settingsObj = {
  0: {
      matchValue: e.target.name,
      value: e.target.value,
      transformType: 'replaceElement'
  }
}
if(e.target.name === 'viewtitle'){
  this.props.updateViewName(e.target.value);
}
this.props.updateViewXMLValue(settingsObj)
this.setState(localState)
}
```

Here is the onBlur event:

```
Title
    </div>
    <div className='tab-input-container'>
     <input name='viewtitle' type='text' className="shape-dropdown" placeholder='Title' defaultValue={this.props.defaultData.viewtitle[0].length === 0 ? null : this.props.defaultData.viewtitle[0]} onBlur={this.handleChange}/>
    </div>
```

Here is my test file:

```
it('Testing onBlur event on ViewTitle', () => {
 baseProps.updateViewName.mockClear();
 wrapper.setProps({
   defaultData:{
    viewtitle:[ [] ],
   }
  });
 wrapper.setState({
    localState: "blur" 
 });
 wrapper.update() 
 wrapper.find('input[name="viewtitle"]').simulate('blur',
 {
   target: { 
    value:'blur-Test', 
    name:'viewtitle'
    }
});
  expect(baseProps.updateViewName).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(wrapper.state('localState')).toEqual('blur-Test'); 
});
```

It seems that target value does not interfere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code: `localState[e.target.name] = e.target.value` the `onBlur` handler sets the state objects `viewtitle` key to whatever the input is.

So if your original state was `{localState: "blur"}`, the new state would be `{localState: "blur", viewtitle: "blur-test" }`, which your test will fail as it is looking at the `localState` key.

Comment: I changed my code a bit and added viewtitle on my set state as well.      viewtitle: "blur-test" `  and then I wrote the following : expect(wrapper.state('viewtitle')).toEqual('blur-test1');`     Since my target:{ value: blur-test1

Comment: I do not see any changes so far, it will only pass if it matches my viewtitle, so its not simulating correctly

Comment: Isn't the target value `blur-Test` and not `blur-test1`?

Comment: I changed in my code just to test it out, but even if I make target 'value = blur test' and  'view tittle = blur test` as well, simulate wont do anything.

Comment: In another words: setstate : viewtitle= 'blur-Test' . When I try to simulate blur, target:{value = "blurTest-1" . So I expect(wrapper.state('localState')).toEqual('blur-Test1'); to equal the value passed and not the setState, correct ?